# Access-Control-Allow-Origin for GCP

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform

I created a small Flask API and deployed it on Google Cloud. It's going to be used by others so I tested running a fetch request, but then I get the following error:

```
Access to fetch at '[API]' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I looked online for ways to enable CORS for GCP, but it seems to only be for buckets and not API services. Is there any other quick workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Something that works is using Flask-CORS instead of dealing with GCP.